# Swiftui failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report

Tags: swift, xcode, imagepicker

Before I select an image from the gallery, I want to have an initial image from SF-Symbole ("photo.fill). But unfortunately it shows me an error.

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug
> report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include
> the project

**The code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var showImagePicker : Bool = false
@State private var image : Image? = nil

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            
           Spacer()
            
            if image? {
                Image(uiImage: image?)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                
            } else {
            Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .opacity(0.6)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Öffne Galerie"){
                self.showImagePicker = true
            }.padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
            PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Foto bearbeiten"))
    }
  }
}
 struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

[image: The code as an image]

Comment: You should be unwrapping your image optional. Currently the syntax you are using is wrong. You should use `if let image = image { … }`

Comment: That error is usually a typo `image?` is not a `Bool`

Comment: How can I fix this?? @loremipsum

Comment: Look at Andrew's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you are unwrapping the optional image incorrectly, you need to use an `if-let` so that you have a non-nil value for your image.

You are also passing an `Image` where you actually require a `UIImage`. This is not something that you can do. You need to make sure that you understand that types that you using and what they represent.

Unfortunately you **did not** include the code for your `PhotoCaptureView` so it is not possible to see what you actually require. This is why you are asked to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you post a question on SO.

However, here is how you can handle it if it requires an `Image` or a `UIImage`, there are similarities to both. Look at the comments in the code for the changes.

### `PhotoCaptureView` uses `Image`

If you are creating an `Image` in the `PhotoCaptureView` then there are two changes that you need to make.

- You need to unwrap your `Image` before you use it
- As you have a SwiftUI Image you can just use it directly.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImagePicker : Bool = false
    @State private var image : Image? = nil

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            VStack {

                Spacer()

                if let image = image { // here we unwrap the Image
                    image              // as we have a SwiftUI Image we can use it directly.
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .opacity(0.6)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                Spacer()

                Button("Öffne Galerie"){
                    self.showImagePicker = true
                }.padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
                PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Foto bearbeiten"))
        }
    }
}
```

### `PhotoCaptureView` uses `UIImage`

However, if your `PhotoCaptureView` requires a `UIImage` then you need to make three changes to your code.

- Firstly we would need to change your `@State` variable from being `Image` into a `UIImage`.
- We can then unwrap the image the same way as above
- We then pass the unwrapped `UIImage` into the initializer for `Image(uiImage:)`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImagePicker : Bool = false
    @State private var image : UIImage? = nil // Here we use UIImage

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            VStack {

                Spacer()

                if let image = image {    // We unwrap the UIImage so that we can use it
                    Image(uiImage: image) // Here we convert the UIImage into a SwiftUI Image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .opacity(0.6)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                Spacer()

                Button("Öffne Galerie"){
                    self.showImagePicker = true
                }.padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
                PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Foto bearbeiten"))
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest that you read up on [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#:%7E:text=and%20Classes.-,Optionals,-You%20use%20optionals) in the Swift documentation, as you seem to have some misconceptions about them.